# Differential system of two functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The functions $x$ and $y$ are defined by
$$x'(t) =y^{2}(t)\qquad\text{and}\qquad y'(t)=-x^{2}(t),$$
initial conditions
$$x(0)=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad y(0)=1.$$

we have $x^3(t)+y^3(t)=1$ for all $t$.

I am looking for references on this subject

Comment: Could you perhaps show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to show that $\frac{x(t)}{y(t)} =-x(-t)$ and  $y(t).y(-t)=1$